# Tag synonym request - Office 365

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request

I would like to see the following tags set as synonyms of [MS-Office-365](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-office-365) :

[Exchange-Online](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/exchange-online)

[MS-Exchange-365](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-exchange-365)

While Exchange Online could be considered a separate offering by Microsoft from Office 365, the synonym linked to MS-Office-365 is likely to draw more expertise on the subject and 95% of the time it will be Office 365 related.

Answer (score 3):

[exchange-online](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/exchange-online) to [ms-office-365](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-office-365), agreed (also 5 of 5 existing questions support your assertion)

[ms-exchange-365](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ms-exchange-365) <strike>doesn't exist and don't think anyone would use it</strike> Done!

Comment: ms-exchange-365 doesn't exist?  I show 7 questions tagged to it.  I can change them to the ms-office-365 tag instead though and let ms-exchange-365 die off if that makes more sense.

Comment: I'll call that a glitch in the Matrix... I swear it showed 0 questions last night.